# Firebase Change App email address

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I am using an firebase app that sends verification and lost password emails to users.

The users get the email form

```
noreply@admob-app-id-123456789.firebaseapp.com
```

How can I change this email address.

Note here that I am using firebase with angularfire for the web.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the email address in the [Firebase Authentication console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/authentication/emails).

[image: Screenshot of Firebase Authentication console]

Specifically:

1. Open your project in the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com)
2. Click <kbd>Authentication</kbd> in the leftnav
3. Click <kbd>TEMPLATES</kbd> in the topnav
4. Click the little pencil icon next to <kbd>From</kbd>